# Can I figure out if my server has IPv4 or IPv6 from a CLI?

Tags: command-line-interface, ipv6, ipv4

Is there any method (via CLI) of knowing if the server I'm at has IPv4 or IPv6?

EDIT:  As for the reason why I'm asking this question (apologies if I wasn't specific enough), I'm referring to [this guide](http://library.linode.com/getting-started#sph_update-etc-hosts) by my host (Linode).

Specifically, they say (under the section about updating /etc/hosts) that:

> "If you have IPv6 enabled on your Linode, you will also want to add an entry for your IPv6 address […]".

So, I'm simply wondering *if and how* you can figure this out via commandline. (My OS is Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric.)

UPDATE: Apart from ifconfig, it seems the **ping6** utility might prove useful, as hinted to in [this](https://library.linode.com/networking/ipv6) article.

Comment: And your O/S is...?

Comment: Also define "has" -- a link-local address, local connectivity, some modicum of global connectivity, all of these are very different things with very different ways of determining their presence or absence.

Comment: Talk to your host! They are the only ones that can tell you if you have IPv6 connectivity.  There's no way we (or you) can determine if the machine has it, but it's unconfigured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a "one or the other" option. You can query the network stack from the command line (see below) and this will return what IP addresses are assigned to each network interface, and you can then see from the format of these addresses which type they are.

`ipconfig` for [windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipconfig)

`ifconfig` for [most *nix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifconfig)

Be aware that just because an address is there, it doesn't mean that it's in use. Many modern operating systems will assign a [link-local address](http://packetlife.net/blog/2011/apr/28/ipv6-link-local-addresses/) to any active network adapter by default these days.

Comment: +1. Chance hare you have both - windows for example has ipv6 autoamtically unless turned off even if no other machien is on the network. So, what you do then? It is both in most cases. And more than one 1ipv6 is common.

Comment: indeed @tomtom - most modern operating systems will configure a local ipV6 address these days by default (OSX 10.7 behaves the same as your windows example too, I think) so the OP needs to appreciate that just because it exists, it doesn't mean the OS is doing anything with it.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Ipconfig pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Aside: the ping6 utility seems to be suitable for testing IPv6 connectivity. E.g:
$ ping6 ipv6.google.com -c 3

Answer (score 4):

ifconfig will help you:

```
 stone@box ~ $ sudo ifconfig
 [sudo] password for stone: 
 eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr aa:00:05:00:0a:02  
           inet addr:192.168.0.2  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
           inet6 addr: fe80::a800:5ff:fe00:a02/64 Scope:Link
           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
           RX packets:8931 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:8250 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
           RX bytes:9244802 (8.8 MiB)  TX bytes:1593148 (1.5 MiB)
           Interrupt:42 Base address:0x4000
```

You will see something like this, the **ipv6 addr** is what matters and **Scope** in the same line. If you see there *Site* then you have IPv6 routed address. (*Link* means only link local address.)

Answer (score 2):

Your system will almost certainly have IPV4. You don't say which OS. You can use `ifconfig` in linux to get and look for an `inet6` line

```
ifconfig | grep inet6 
inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe5b:a5ea/64 Scope:Link
```

or you can use `ipconfig` under windows and look for `IPv6 Address` in the output.

Comment: I am also almost definite using ipv4 on linux, because your command did not return `Scope:Link` at the end of my output. I got two lines output where `inet6` is red